# What is this query supposed to do? (and why does it fail?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm tasked with revive this old piece of legacy software.
It used to run on an old server (2012) which has died the ugly way (hard disk failure).
Before this server died, the code worked without problems.

I've rebuild the MySQL database and data from backups.

However, one query is does not work and fails with error: `Query preparation failed: Unknown column '_operationId' in 'where clause'`. The query in question is:

```
SELECT
  @r AS _operationId
, @r := (
    SELECT
      operationId
    FROM operations
    WHERE operationId = _operationId
  ) AS includesOperationId
FROM (SELECT  @r := %i) AS tmp
INNER JOIN operations
WHERE @r > 0 AND @r IS NOT NULL
```

From what I understand, the query tries to join back onto itself building a tree of some sort??

For some reason, this query must have worked on some previous version of MySQL (5.0??) but with the current version (MySQL 5.7) the query fails.

Is there any 'mysql whisperer' out there who can explain to me:

1. what the query attempts to do?
2. why it worked on some previous version but not anymore?
3. how to change the query to make it work again?

thanks a million in advance.

**Update:**
The `operations` table definition and data:

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| operationId | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| operation   | varchar(40)         | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| description | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| operationId | operation | description |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|           1 | add       | NULL        |
|           2 | delete    | NULL        |
|           3 | edit      | NULL        |
|           4 | view      | NULL        |
|           5 | disable   | NULL        |
|           6 | execute   | NULL        |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: I'm an SQL Server guy so probably can't help, however if you give some sample data, maybe table schema too, that would be a huge help for those who are professional with MySQL to understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: I doubt that query ever worked on any version,as it is.

Comment: Your code suggests that `_operationid` is also a variable in the environment.  Sure is weird to be using session variables (with `@` and procedural variables) in the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is attempting to do some sort of tree traversal. I don't know that it would work in any version of MySQL, but my best guess is that the intention is something like this:

```
SELECT @r AS _operationId,
       @r := (SELECT operationId
              FROM operations
              WHERE operationId = @r
             ) AS includesOperationId
FROM operations CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @r := %i) params
WHERE @r > 0 AND @r IS NOT NULL;
```

Having said that, if this *happens* to work, there is no guarantee that it will work again or in another version of MySQL. This violates two rules of using variables:

- A variable assigned in one expression in a `SELECT` should not be used in another. The order of evaluation of expressions is not defined, so the expressions could be evaluated in any order.
- There is not guarantee on when the conditions in the `WHERE` clause using variables are evaluated and definitely no guarantee about some sort of "sequential" evaluation with respect to the `SELECT`.

The subquery is also problematic.

The good news is that if `operations` has no column called `_operationId`, then the query should fail on all versions of MySQL with an undefined column type of error (although perhaps older versions did something funky).

The bad news is that if you want to walk through a hierarchy in MySQL, you either need to change the data structure or use a stored procedure.

Comment: BUMP! I love this answer! Here, take my upvote :) Now what "Ifu" could clarify is, what and where calls the SP and what do we think, what kind of result set the caller expects?

Comment: I expected that the `_operationId` in the inner query somehow referred to the `_operationId` in the outer query, or at least that it used to do so in the old mysql version.

Comment: @Mark, the code seems to expect two columns, with an operationId in both. I think those ids are expected to be hierarchical.

Comment: @ifu Yup, I get that. And based on the sample table schema my assumption is there were "operations" on something with an ID and an 'action' and all these were chained, so one can get a full edit/manipulation history on any given item by unpicking this series. What I'm saying is, you should look into the code. Maybe ask another question after code analysis how to implement the SP correctly. I find Mr. Linoff's answer full and complete tbh :)